# Is there a way to turn on anti-aliasing?

Tags: quantum-conundrum

I've become spoiled by modern graphics.  I'd like anti-aliasing in this game, but there isn't an option for it in the menus.  Is there a way to turn it on?

---

I've found [this steam forum post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=31264448), but either I am doing something wrong or it doesn't work for me.  Maybe someone else will have better luck and be able to clarify the process for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your computer's video card control panel to force the anti-aliasing technique of your choice for this particular game.

Open NVIDIA Control Panel -> Manage 3D Settings -> Program Settings -> Add -> Navigate to the executable file for the game -> Antialiasing (FXAA) -> On